# Mongoose find field in array not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've an application running in Node.js and mongodb with mongoose as the driver. I've created a login function and just for debugging purpose, I print out the document after querying. Here is my code:

mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532cec102e42bcfced71fe03"),
    "admins" : [ 
        {
            "username" : "matthew",
            "name" : "lol",
            "hidden" : {
                "password" : "f8d822f6fab9dfc3c7b3a5035cdc422aee3bb838",
                "access" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "username" : "matthew1",
            "name" : "2000",
            "hidden" : {
                "password" : "40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef",
                "access" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "location" : "SZ",
    "hidden" : {
        "global_access" : true
    },
    "token" : "f10e2821bbbea527ea02200352313bc059445190"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53307831a6b6ecd28c5cacd7"),
    "admins" : [ 
        {
            "username" : "matthew123123",
            "name" : "lol",
            "hidden" : {
                "password" : "f8d822f6fab9dfc3c7b3a5035cdc422aee3bb838",
                "access" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "username" : "matthew1222222",
            "name" : "2000",
            "hidden" : {
                "password" : "40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef",
                "access" : false
            }
        }
    ],
    "location" : "SH",
    "hidden" : {
        "global_access" : true
    },
    "token" : "f10e2821bbbea527ea02200352313bc159445190"
}
```

branches.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');


 var db = mongoose.connection;
 var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    name: String,
    hidden: {
        password: String,
        access: Boolean
    }
 });

 var branchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    admins: [adminSchema],
    location: String,
    hidden: {
        global_access: Boolean
    },
    token: String
 });

 var branch = mongoose.model('branch', branchSchema);
 var admin = mongoose.model('admin', adminSchema);

 exports.login = function(req,res){
    var user = new admin(req.body, null, true)
    user.hidden.password = sha1(user.hidden.password);
    console.log(user);

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/branches');
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback()
    {
        console.log('connected to database');
        branch.findOne({
        },
        {
            "admins": 
            {
                $elemMatch : 
                {
                    username: user.username, 
                    'hidden.password': user.hidden.password,
                }
            }
        })
        .exec(
        function (err,doc){
            db.close();
            res.send(doc);
        });
    });
 };
```

I made a request sending in the data:

```
{
    username:'matthew',
    hidden.password:'200169+'
}
```

and it returned the result:

```
{
    "_id": "532cec102e42bcfced71fe03",
    "admins": []
}
```

however, I was expected to see the result something like this:

```
{
    "admins": [
        {
            "username":"matthew,
            "name":"lol"
        }
    ],
    "token":"f10e2821bbbea527ea02200352313bc059445190"
}
```

I suspect that the query was wrong, since if I send in any random combinations of username and password, it still gives the same result. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with the [`findOne()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) statement in your code.  The syntax of findOne() is:

```
db.collection.findOne(<criteria>, <projection>)
```

If you pass an empty JSON to the criteria, it is equivalent to not specifying any criteria and MongoDB returns the first document according to the [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order) of the documents on disk.  Since your query contains an empty json as the query criteria and only provides the projection criteria, MongoDB always returns the first document on the disk and applies the projection criteria on it.  As the returned document doesn't match the projection, you are getting an empty array.

You should try something like:

```
    ...
    branch.findOne({
        "admins": 
        {
            $elemMatch : 
            {
                username: user.username, 
                'hidden.password': user.hidden.password,
            }
        }
    },
    {"admins.$":1, token:1}
    )
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! however I'm still getting the other admin's entry (matthew1), is this something to do with the projection statement maybe?

Comment: I've edited the post to include a projection.  You should see the expected result now.